# Akamai Adaptive Bitrate streaming

Tags: akamai

Trying to find some information on how to setup my Akamai for adaptive bitrate streaming - Havn't been able to find much of anything... I tried to post on the developer forums but it wouldn't let me login... not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your streaming  format?

Comment: we are streaming using wirecast with our rtmp info - pretty sure the our stream goes into our player (clappr) as .m3u8

Comment: still need help?

Comment: yes @JoeSlav - have you done this before?

Comment: Ok. Just to understand better -- have you asked at community.akamai.com? Do you have a Luna login account? Which format are you trying to setup (vod or live, ingestion format, delivery format?)

Comment: @JoeSlav I haven't asked on the community forums - I do have a luna login account  stream on wirecast to the rtmp and it comes in as .m3u8. streaming both live and vod.

Comment: If you have a luna login account you can click on the "Support" link on the top-right corner, then "User and Developers Guides" and then select "Media Services Live" and then "Media Services Live: Stream Packaging (RTMP Ingest/ HDS & HLS Outputs) User Guide". This guides will teach you everything you need to know regarding live streaming which takes an RTMP stream and returns an HLS one. I do advise you to get on the community and ask there if you have any issue!

Comment: For vod you would select "Media Services On Demand" and then "Media Services On Demand: Stream Packaging User Guide".

Answer (score 0):

For RTMP ingest to HLS/HDS output, you'll want to configure a live stream using Media Services Live 3.2. The functionality is called "Stream Packaging" and is configured through the "Media Services Live" option under "CONFIGURE" in the Luna service.

[image: Media Services Live link in Luna]

Full details are available through [learn.akamai.com](https://learn.akamai.com) by searching for "[Provisioning Media Services Live: Stream Packaging](https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/media-services-live/media-services-live-stream-packaging-rtmp-ingest-hds-and-hls-outputs-user-guide/GUID-DF94BF14-7086-4A08-BD2D-C75250C71D1E.html)".